# Connect directly through an instance in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to connect to an instance directly without specifying a server and the username and password? So instead of

```
 connectionString = @"server=serverName" + "other things and password"
```

It'll be:

```
 connectionString = [direct instance connect]
```

Comment: You can use Integrated Security=True if your logged user are able to connect in your sql server

Comment: Also will a behavior of a program differ if the data source is a standalone instance (and not connected to a server) if connected to a server?

Comment: Is it a contextual connection meant for SQLCLR? If not then you *must* feed the connection string with minimal informations about the location and credentials. If what you mean is how you can do that without hardcoding the location and credentials, update your question accordingly. Right now it's unclear what your requirements are.

Comment: Well it's this program that I have here that uses a database that I thought wasn't in a server and just a standalone instance. The email indicates me to stop the service.Then after reading all this and looking at the services and in Configuration Manager there is a server (yeah, stupid)

Comment: That's why I asked if there's a way to connect to a instance directly to have an idea of the behavior of the program if I were to connect it to one. But never mind now hahaha. Regards everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to connect without specifying server but you can active `Windows Authentication` on SQL Server and use `Integrated Security=True` to connect without username and password.

Comment: just because the op doesn't want to write the whole connection string again and again advising them to switching to a whole different authentication mode seems a bit radical change to me. we have `System.Configuration` name space to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to store your connection strings in the web.config file something like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CS1" 
      connectionString="server=ServerName;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />

<add name="CS2" 
      connectionString="server=ServerName2;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And when initialization a connection use the following, don't have to pass the whole shebang of server name , user name , pass etc

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following link to find out all of the ways you can connect:

```
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
```

and also try this:

```
"Data Source=server\\instance;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but I expect it is because this is mostly a link only answer

Comment: Question is not about how to setup a connection string, it's "how to connect to Sql Server without specifying a server location" - which is probably too much of a silly question for it to get a pertinent answer anyway. :)